# How is the correct way to get values ​from a web service

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am practicing the consumption of a web service made in soap from xamarin, but I am having problems when trying to consume the service, because what I want to do is obtain its return values, both the id and another value, but at the moment of receiving the y values read them in a para, the id is just the position of the array, but not the value I need. 
This is my stored procedure:

```
IF @Action = 1 --Traer Surtidor
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            Id_Surtidor,
            Numero_Surtidor
        FROM
            Bit_V3.dbo.Surtidores
        WHERE
            Id_Eds = @Id_Eds
END
```

This is my service:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable SpinnerSurtidorConsulta(string id_eds)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable Dt;
        DCL.Apertura_Combustible Consumible = new DCL.Apertura_Combustible();
        Consumible.Id_Eds = id_eds;
        Dt = Apertura_Combustible_BLR.SelectTable(Consumible, 1);
        return Dt;
    }
    catch (Exception Op)
    {
        throw Op;
    }
}
```

This is my archive.cs:

```
ServicesConsultas.ServiceCombustible proxy = new ServicesConsultas.ServiceCombustible();
proxy.SpinnerSurtidorConsultaCompleted += Proxy_SpinnerSurtidorConsultaCompleted;

var ta = 2;

proxy.SpinnerSurtidorConsultaAsync(ta.ToString());

Dictionary<int, string> dict_surtidor = new Dictionary<int, string>();
private void Proxy_SpinnerSurtidorConsultaCompleted(object sender, ServicesConsultas.SpinnerSurtidorConsultaCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dtb = e.Result;
    if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dict_surtidor.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < dtb.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dict_surtidor.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dtb.Rows[i][0].ToString()), dtb.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, dict_surtidor.Values.ToArray());
    adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    spinner2.Adapter = adapter;
    spinner2.ItemSelected += Spinner2_ItemSelected;
}
```

Comment: there is no way to answer this without knowing anything about the service you are using.  There are thousands of different ways to implement a web service.

Comment: I don't see a call to a service here. I don't know what "y values" or "para" or "id" or "the array" are.

Comment: @Jason I already added my service

Comment: @cosmosmulti how was the service client generated?

Comment: @DanielA.White via web reference

Comment: have you tried getting the result of `proxy.SpinnerSurtidorConsultaAsync` into a variable?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, but I don't know the best way to do that.

Comment: it returns a DataTable.  So what you really need to know is how to use a DataTable.  That's fairly well documented, what have you tried?

Comment: @Jason What I am trying to use is a spinner, for that I use a for loop, to go through what the web service returns, and I enter it into a dictionary, but when I do that I only save the indexes of the for but not the id that me the web service returns.

Comment: again, I don't know anything about the DataTable that your service returns so I can't tell you how to extract the data from it.

Comment: @Jason I hope this change is useful to you

Comment: if you want the **int key** of your dictionary, use `.Keys` instead of `.Values`